# Modeling spiral inside the square

Tags: modeling

I have spiral inside the square. I need to subdivide the square in that way to connect the edges to spiral so that I get correct faces inside the spiral.

How to do that?

http://www.mediafire.com/file/9wwyjd3x25uel3m/spiral.blend

[image]

Comment: Subdivide square once, there will be enough vertices to make quads between spiral and square. You might need to scale square vertices a bit out to avoid stretched faces